# site-to-site transfer (FXP) error

Tags: ftp, iis-6

I'm enabled site to site transfer in IIS6 like this:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/247132

but i receive this error in cuteftp program:

```
STATUS:>    [2011-10-15 11:45:24 PM] Site-to-site configuration #2: source - PORT, destination - PASV.
COMMAND:>   [2011-10-15 11:45:24 PM] DST: TYPE I
        [2011-10-15 11:45:24 PM] DST: 200 Type set to I.
COMMAND:>   [2011-10-15 11:45:24 PM] SRC: TYPE I
        [2011-10-15 11:45:24 PM] SRC: 200 Type set to I.
COMMAND:>   [2011-10-15 11:45:24 PM] DST: PASV
        [2011-10-15 11:45:25 PM] DST: 227 Entering Passive Mode (*,*,*,*,16,14).
COMMAND:>   [2011-10-15 11:45:25 PM] SRC: PORT *,*,*,*,16,14
        [2011-10-15 11:45:26 PM] SRC: 500 Invalid PORT Command.
ERROR:>     [2011-10-15 11:45:26 PM] SRC: Syntax error: command unrecognized.
ERROR:>     [2011-10-15 11:45:26 PM] Site-to-site transfer failed.
```

Answer (score 2):

turn off passive mode on the client

Passive mode uses a random port to transfer data.. active mode will use port 20